# Vectors vs. Points

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In Rudin’s PMA(specifically in chapter two), he seems to treat vectors and points as the same thing. Is this valid, or am I incorrect?

Comment: Depends on the context. A vector is an an element of a vector space, where by definition there is a notion of adding two vectors and of multiplying a vector by a scalar. Within the context of a vector space (particularly if finite dimensional), it's reasonable to consider points and vectors as the same thing. But Rudin's PMA chapter 2 is about metric spaces, and in a metric space in general there need not be a notion of adding points or multiplying points by scalars. In that case you would not normally refer to metric space elements as vectors.

Comment: Of course some spaces are both metric spaces and vector spaces, where again it makes sense to identify vectors and points.

Comment: The terms "point" and "vector" are both overloaded and have different meanings in different contexts. The most common definitions that I use, in my mind, are that "point" and "vector" both mean "ordered $n$-tuple of numbers", but if you call an ordered $n$-tuple a "point" then you are giving the reader a hint that they should visualize it as a location in space, and if you call an ordered $n$-tuple a "vector" you are giving the reader a hint that they should visualize it as a directed line segment (representing the displacement between two points).

Answer (score 1):

There is a one-to-one correspondence between vectors in Euclidean space and points in Euclidean space. So it is common to identify a vector with a point and conversely.

Answer (score 0):

Co-ordinates of a points A, B, C w.r.t. to an origin is called position vectors, to be denoted as $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$. But $\vec{AB}$ is called absolute vector and from triangula law $$\vec{AB}=\vec{AO}+\vec{OB}= -\vec a+ \vec b= \vec b- \vec a$$

Interestingly the position vectors and (absolute) vectors are written alike as $a\vec j + b \vec j + c\vec k$. In a problen one sjould know very well whether the given vectors PV oe absolute ones.

For instance PVs $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ form a triabgle If these PVs are not proportion to each other. Or if $\vec c=m \vec a+m \vec b$, such that $1-m-n\ne 0$. Namely, when three points are non-collinear.

Three vectors $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$ form a triangle if sum of two equals the third or minus times third (critically): $\vec a+ \vec b=\vec c ~~or~~ -\vec c.$